# Need some basic github help

Tags: ruby-on-rails, version-control, github, terminal, osx-leopard

I am trying to learn github to deploy a webpage. Here are the steps I am taking:

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git checkout –b my-awesome-branch
```

Do some work, do a git status to check on everything, everything is ok.

```
git add .
git commit –m "awesome message here"
git push origin my-awesome-branch
git checkout integration
git merge my-awesome-branch
git push origin integration
cap development deploy
```

this will push a file to the dev server we have so people can look at it - this worked fine for me you won't be able to see the link but it generates something like this:

```
http://dev.mywebsite.com/events/email/welcome
```

Let's go live (pretending there are no further changes)

```
git checkout master
git merge my-awesome-branch
git push origin master
cap production deploy
```

In theory, the file should push to the live website (which would be `http://mywebsite.com/events/email/welcome`) but that webpage is not created when i cap production deploy.

Another developer more familiar with this system says :

> It looks like you forked "my party events" repo and have pushed the
>   master there. You'll want to push master to the upstream remote (the
>   main "my party events", or my_events repo.)

I don't follow this step. Can anyone follow this logic? If so, do you have a suggestion for me on what i may be doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a forked branch on **Github**, that means you have a copy of the entire git repo under your name.  Check your Github account to verify this.

To do this, go to `https://github.com/your-github-user-name-here`.  On the left side, look for "my-party-events" (assuming that's the repo name).  Underneath it, look for `"forked from xyz/my-party-events"`.

If you don't see `'forked from ...'`, then you're the original owner of that repo.  This shouldn't be the case.

If you do see `'forked from ...'`, then you have a copy under your name (that's what a fork is).  Any changes you make to a fork don't affect the original repo.

If you're with me up to here, there's 2 ways you can go.

**Via Git** (Recommended)

Whenever you did a `git pull` or `git push` earlier, you were specifying **origin**, which is a human-readable name for a repo that you set up earlier.  The repo address actually looks like this

```
git@github.com:your-user-name/project-name.git
```

As you can see, referring to it by a nickname like 'origin' is way easier to remember.

**Assuming you have write access** to the main project repo, you can just add another repo to your config.  **Make sure you have write access before attempting this**, otherwise you're just wasting your time.  Ask your coworker if you're not sure.

Lets say you wanted to nickname the repo as 'production', you would do this

```
git remote add production git@github.com:PROJECT_OWNER/project-name.git
```

The git repo address looks almost identical to your fork repo.  It differs only by username.  On the front page of all Github projects, the repo address is in a text field.  It's next to the "SSH | HTTPS | Git Read-only" buttons.  Get the address from there, replace it in the command above, and finally, do this in your command line

```
git push production master
```

From now on, you can just `git push production master`, which is pretty simple.  If you don't have write access, then you'll have to submit changes via pull requests.

**Through the Website**

You can submit a pull request to the repo you forked from.  A pull request asks the original repo admin to include changes you've made on your fork.

To submit a pull request, click on your project fork from your projects page.  Look for the 'Pull Request' icon near the top right.  That should take you to a page where you can choose the target and source branches.